# Null Pointer Exception at batch.begin() LibgDDX

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, libgdx

I am trying to draw a .png to the screen, but I keep getting an error. The class I am working with is a subclass of Screen.

Here is the error I get:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION GLThread 1335 java.lang.NullPointerException  at SplashScreen.java.32
```

this line is:

```
batch.begin()
```

Here is my code inside of the Screen subclass:

```
private SpriteBatch batch;
private Texture splashTexture;
private Camera camera;


 final int CAMERA_WIDTH = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();



@Override
public void render(float delta) {
   Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
   Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
   batch.begin();
   batch.draw(splashTexture, 0, 0);
   batch.end();

}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void show() {
   splashTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("splash.png"));
   camera = new OrthographicCamera(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
    camera.position.set(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT, 0);
}
```

Comment: did you try to debug ? add the batch = new SpriteBatch(); to show() and make a breakpoint go on from there , i tried with exact same code and it works for me

Comment: Very weird, after I add a breakpoint to batch.begin(); it works?! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your SpriteBatch is null, you create your texture and your camera but you don't create the batch. the breakpoint you mention has nothing to do with it.

```
private SpriteBatch batch;
private Texture splashTexture;
private Camera camera;

...

@Override
public void show(){
    splashTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("splash.png"));
    camera = new OrthographicCamera(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
    camera.position.set(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT, 0);

    batch = new SpriteBatch(); //create it like this.
}

...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
batch=new spritebatch();
```

and your problem is sloved.

Comment: Worked for me. Just need to capitalize the S and B in SpriteBatch.